# Ruby, Convert String Queries Into Method Calls

Tags: ruby, string, methods, translate

The code below works completely fine as long as users enter in the method name. I'd like to avoid requiring users to enter the name of the method at the various gets.chomp prompts.

I thought that using a case statement to translate the user input into method calls would work, but I keep getting a .include? NoMethodDefined error.

```
class Foo

  def initialize(start_action)
    @start = start_action
  end

  def play
    next_action = @start
    while true
      case next_action.include?
      when beginning
        next_action = beginning
      when "instruct"
        next_action = instructions # returns instructions as
                                   # the method that's called below
      when "users"
        next_action = users # returns users as the
                            # method that's called below
      else 
        puts "Unknown command."
        next_action = # some placeholder method call that gets the user
                      # back to being able to make another choice
      end 
      puts "\n----------"
      next_action = method(next_action).call
  end

  def beginning
    puts "This is the beginning."
    next_action = gets.chomp
  end

  def instructions
    puts "These are the instructions"
    # code to display instructions omitted
    next_action = gets.chomp
  end

  def users
    puts "Here are your users"
    # code to display users omitted
    next_action = gets.chomp
  end

end

start = Foo.new(:beginning)
start.play
```

Any advice or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On the first pass through your loop, `next_action` is the symbol `:beginning` and symbols don't have an `include?` method.

In addition I think you've misunderstood how case statements work - even removing the first error your code will then complain that you're passing 0 arguments to `include?` (instead of 1)

I think you instead mean something like

```
case next_action
when /instruct/
  ..
when /users
   ..
else
  ..
end
```

Which will test next action against each regular repression in turn

Comment: Ah, yes. Makes sense. Ok, so, now I've refactored per your suggestion and I no longer get the NoMethodError, but I seem to have broken the while loop. And it isn't recognizing "instruct" or "users" as valid options. All I get is one Unknown Command, then anything entered into the next prompt exits the process. I'm expecting to get passed back into the loop.

Comment: Your current code doesn't look like it will ever call the beginning method

Comment: I fixed the case statement to include beginning as an option. It's actually the first method that's called, yes? When Foo is initialized? Regardless, even if I type one of the other options, the case statement isn't recognizing them. All I'm getting is the Unknown Command option. I'll type [users] at the prompt (without the brackets), and the case statement thinks it's no good.

Comment: In your code as it stands the case statement is executing beginning and matching next_action against the return value of that method rather matching next_action against the literal "beginning"

Comment: Ok. So then the sequence is like this: Initialize Class. next_action = beginning. case chooses beginning. call beginning. user choice = x. back to play. case chooses else no matter what the user choice is? Why?

Comment: Well at this point it's hard to help since you've presumably made code changes that aren't reflected in the question